# Elapsed time of malloc after populating unordered_map (c++)

Tags: c++, performance, malloc, unordered-map

in the following code, I implemented and populated an `unordered_map` (function `unuseful()`), then I used `malloc` to allocate memory. The time elapsed for the malloc call is very high (more or less 135 milliseconds to store 1001 bytes): why?

I'm compiling using gcc4.8.1, which runs on Lubuntu 13.10. The compile command is `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp` (if I add optimization like `-O1`, `-O2`, `-O3`, `-Ofast` or `-Wno-write-strings`, the result does not change). I'm testing the efficiency of a (much more complex) program, and I really need to understand which parts take how much time.

If I remove the function `unuseful()` or move the code from the function `unuseful()` to the main function, the time becomes 0. If I allocate 1000 bytes and not 1001, the time becomes 0. If I repeat twice the experiment using a for loop, the time of the first experiment is again 135 milliseconds, the time of the second is 0.

The code follows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

void unuseful() {
    unordered_map <string, int> nodes;
    for (int nn = 0; nn < 1000000; nn++) {
        nodes[to_string(nn)] = nn;
    }
}

long getTimeMilliseconds() {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return tv.tv_usec / 1000 + tv.tv_sec * 1000;
}

int main() {
    unuseful();

    long start = getTimeMilliseconds();
    int *dist = (int*) malloc(1001);
    cout << "Time: " << getTimeMilliseconds() - start << "\n";
    cout << "Something unuseful to avoid compiler optimizations: " << dist[1000] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Using `malloc()` in C++ code is often considered sub-optimal - you should be using `int *dist = new int[1001]` instead (followed by a `delete[] dist` at some later point. Or even better, use a `std::vector` or other suitable class...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Why do you say that malloc() is sub-optimal? I'm very concerned about performances, and malloc() is faster (at least on a test with my computer, using the code I found [here](http://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/2008/09/19/c-array-vs-c-vector/)). I added a test for new and delete, and even in that case the c array is faster (about 2x).

Comment: "Sub-optimal" as in, "that's C, not C++". On some platforms, `new` is implemented via `malloc()`, but on others it isn't, so it may be essentially identical performance-wise, but then again, it may not be - at least for the allocation itself. `new` probably seems slower because it also initializes the memory it returns via default constructors, so it does more than `malloc()` does...

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the heap gets over complicated, and at the exit of the unuseful() method when nodes is released the heap is fragmented, them the first malloc provokes a heap syncrhonization. For a reason I don't understand if the malloc it 1000 the heap is not cleaned up...
Does it behave the same way if you retain the nodes map ?

Another idea: What if you remove the unuseful() call ? Doesn't the compiler initializes 'start and calls getTimeMilliseconds before unuseful() ?

Comment: If I retain the nodes map (for example by returning it in the unuseful() function), the malloc time becomes 0, as if I remove the unuseful() call. However, if I move the initialization of start before unuseful(), the time is 722 milliseconds. The only possibility is that only a part of the unuseful() function is executed after the start initialization (strange, I think).